# How to protect credential in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, angular5

I am using `Angular 5` with `Firebase`, i understand the firebase `credential` in `Angular` has the chance to leak to client side when rendering the pages. But `Firebase Products` can use `rules` to secure it, i found it doesn't harm any to me.

But i have another question, what if I want to use `SQL` or any other services that require credential to perform authentication before executing an action, such as read/write from a SQL table.

When I using `Node.js`, the credential will declare in the server-side JS file, but apparently `Angular` is client-side framework. So i would like to know to solve this problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Code on your server/node app won't be available to the frontend.
Only data that's requested by the client via http requests is available to the Angular app.

So as long you don't return the critical data through your api you're good to go.

Comment: What if i don't use server/node app, how to read/write to SQL DB which require credential?

Comment: You don‘t access DBs from the frontend?!